# How to show different languages subtitles on HTML5 Video Player through JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm making a HTML5 Video Player with number of different languages subtitles. I want to show my subtitles through the `VTTCue` method only. So far my `VTTCue` works for English perfectly, but it doesn't work with other languages like hindi, urdu, chinese, japanese, korean and even Spanish. It does not show some of the character of Spanish language such as `ó` or `á`. Instead it shows something very different. Please help me. And I only want to show the subtitles through the `VTTCue` method only. Thanks

My Code:

```
<html>
<head>
  <title></title>
</head>
<body>
  <video width="640" height="360" src="video.mp4" controls></video>
  <script>
    var video_player = document.querySelector('video');
    var track = undefined;
    track = video_player.addTextTrack("subtitles", undefined, "es");
    track.mode = "showing";
    track.addCue(new VTTCue(0, 10, "cómo están"));
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: so what _does_ it show?   Perhaps you need to page content to be declared to be in UTF-8 ?

Comment: for `á` it shows `A¡`. How do I declare that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect you need to set your charset.

A charset defines what characters can be used. While standard English characters are generally safe, characters from other languages can easily be unrecognizable by the default charset.

According to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5746798/6009304), the UTF-8 charset should be used for multilingual content.

According to [W3Schools](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_charset.asp), you can use this to set your charset in HTML4 Standard:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=UTF-8">
```

You can also use this for HTML5 Standard:

```
<meta charset="UTF-8">
```

These lines would go inside the page's head tag.

Comment: How do I set my charset?